# Tensorflow does not use GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I am using an MSI GL63 8RD-455IN 2018 laptop, with the following hardware and software features:

```
    - NVidia GTX 1050 ti
    - Driver version - Nvidia 398.92
    - OS : Win 10/64
    - keras version : 2.2.2
    - python : 3.6.5
    - tensorflow version : 1.10.0 - gpu
```

The issue is, the tensorflow is not using the GPU. I installed Cuda 9 and Cudnn libraries and installed tensorflow only after the installations of cuda was successful.

I also conducted the primary checks denoted by solutions to see if GPU is being used and these are the results:

```
    print(device_lib.list_local_devices())

    [name: "/device:CPU:0"
    device_type: "CPU"
    memory_limit: 268435456
    locality {
    }
    incarnation: 2797024620588530864
    , name: "/device:GPU:0"
    device_type: "GPU"
    memory_limit: 3168377241
    locality {
    bus_id: 1
    links {
    }
    }
    incarnation: 6850620683865695635
    physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, pci bus id: 
    0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1"
    ]
```

The reason for my doubts is the GPU usage indicator, from **MSI dragon center**. Though it could be suggested that it is not the apt measure/metric, I notice that while using for games, the indicator shows the use of GPU, but while running the code, only the inbuilt RAM seems to be used.

[image]

How can I get my code to use the GPU?

**More Info**

laptop info in this [link](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B07DF151TX/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

Please inform if more info is required.

Comment: Do you have a sample program that doesn't use the GPU? It could be a problem with the program itself and not the system.

Comment: yeah, I tried it with uninstalling tensorflow-gpu and using tensorflow. The program ran much slower, and instead of the memory meter, it was the cpu meter that was under use. I believe the gpu meter is just for the video display. Can you add morte points based on this info?

Comment: Look at this page for a tip on how to log device placement and see if it is indeed using the GPU: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu